# Room Entity with Kotlin Set Field Warning

Tags: android, kotlin, type-conversion, android-room

I am trying to store a "set" of an enum class in a room table :

```
enum class MyEnum { A, B, C }

@Entity(tableName="testtable")
data class TestEntity(
   @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
   val id:Int
   ...
   val mySet:Set<MyEnum> = setOf(MySet.A, MySet.B)
)
```

Initially this failed to compile as it needed a type converter :

```
class MyTypeConverters {

   @TypeConverter
   fun fromMyEnumSet(source:Set<MyEnum>) =
      source.joinToString(",")

   @TypeConverter
   fun toMyEnumSet(source:String):Set<MyEnum> =
      source.split(",").filter{it.isNotEmpty()}.map{MyEnum.valueOf(it.trim())}.toSet()

}
```

It now compiles, but I am getting the following warning :

warning: .../database.entities.TestEntity's mySet field has type java.util.Set<? extends .../database.entities.MyEnum> but its getter returns java.util.Set<.../database.entities.MyEnum>. This mismatch might cause unexpected mySet values in the database when .../entities.TestEntity is inserted into database.
private java.util.Set<? extends .../entities.MyEnum> mySet;

Any ideas how I should fix this issue ?